# How to get all nested tags and text in an xml, inside a particular tag?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup, nested

> ```
> xmlstring="<a> <b> <c> Hello </c> </b> </a>"
> ```

I want to extract all the content "inside" `<b> </b>` tags,

for this I used

```
  content = "".join(xmlstring)
  bs_content = bs(content, "lxml")

  for b_text in bs_content.find_all("b"):
      inside_text = b_text.get_text()
```

but `inside_text` is `Hello` instead of `<c> Hello </c>`

How do I write code to get `<c> Hello </c>` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for that the children method and extract the second element since when calling `find_all("b")` it's returning the  `<b> <c> Hello </c> </b>` item.

```
xmlstring="<a> <b> <c> Hello </c> </b> </a>"
content = "".join(xmlstring)
bs_content = bs(content, "lxml")
for b_text in bs_content.find_all("b"):
    print(" ".join([str(i) for i in b_text.children if i != " "]))
```

Ouput

```
<c> Hello </c>
```

Comment: can you explain the last line, what does `[1]` do?

Comment: This doesn't work for this input `"<a> <b> <c> Hello </c> <d> World </d> </b>   </a>`

Comment: `b_text.children` in a generator that returns 3 parts in this case " " for the first b tag "<c> Hello </c>" that is the second item at index1 and another " "for the second b tag.

Comment: For `"<a> <b> <c> Hello </c> <d> World </d> </b>   </a>"` it's returning `<c> Hello </c>`

Comment: You can use `print([i for i in b_text.children if i != " "])` that will retun in `"<a> <b> <c> Hello </c> <d> World </d> </b>   </a>"` output `[<c> Hello </c>, <d> World </d>]`

Comment: it should return entire text between <b> and </b> i.e. `<c> Hello </c> <d> World </d>` in this case.

Comment: It's splitting the children by tags. you can use `print(" ".join([str(i) for i in b_text.children if i != " "]))` to get them together.

Answer (score 2):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


xmlstring="<a> <b> <c> Hello </c> </b> </a>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(xmlstring, 'lxml')

print( ''.join(str(c) for c in soup.select_one('b').contents) )
```

Prints:

```
 <c> Hello </c>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is specific to this particular input. the identity of inside tags (whether <c> or anything else) is not known.

Comment: @xxx374562 Yes, that's why I only find tag `<b>` and print the contents of this tag, regardless what's indise.